# Error having users update Google Play Services

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I'm making an android app using Google Maps API v2.
Since it requires sort of latest version of google play services I added this code below in OnResume().

```
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

// Check Google Play Service Available
try {
    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 10, new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Runnable r = new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        onBackPressed();

                    }

                };
                r.run();
            }
        }).show();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error: GooglePlayServiceUtil: ", "" + e);

}
```

It works fine on phones with android 4.4 and over(when the phone doesn't have latest version an alert dialog pops up and when i click OK the google play services update page comes up)  but in android 4.0 it crashes when I click OK.

I just can't figure out exactly why this is happening.
on logcat,
i get some null pointer exception

```
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult
```

etc.

So, how can i have the old os users to get to the update page right away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(status)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 10, new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                onBackPressed();

                            }

                        };
                        r.run();
                    }
                }).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
```

Comment: Sounds legit. I'll try it. thx.. by the way, I added an intent to the internet  page for google play services on google play store after the toast code.